# JIRA - pass credentials for a webrequest to API?

Tags: httpwebrequest, jira, credentials

Trying to build a service that will grab info on a JIRA ticket based on an ID passed to it.

I'm calling the API to take the ID passed to the service, tack it onto the URL for the API and get the JSON object.
Problem is, it appears one must be logged on or registered on JIRA in order to use the API.

So if I use the code below to make my request, I get a 404 error, as I do on any browser which I've not used to log onto Jira

```
public string Get(string id)
 {
 string html = string.Empty;
 string url = @"https://company.atlassian.net/rest/api/latest/issue/" + id;

 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
 using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
 using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
 {
 html = reader.ReadToEnd();
 }


return html;

 }
```

I can add credentials to the request like so

```
 request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("vinnie@company.com","mypassword");
```

but I've no idea exactly what needs sending. I've tried the email address with which I'm set up in Jira but that doesn't work.

I have a suspicion that Jira adds a cookie to my browser which it uses to validate after the initial config - is that so?  If so, what can I add/include on my web request to get it to run?

Am I just wildly off on the right way to access it? Or are there changes that can be made to the Jira side to allow requests?

Answer (score 0):

You have to encode your credentials in Base64 format first and then these credentials can be put into your request as shown below:

```
string mergedCredentials = string.Format("{0}:{1}", m_Username, m_Password);
byte[] byteCredentials = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(mergedCredentials);
string base64Credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(byteCredentials);

request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Credentials);
```

Hope you're able to solve your problem by this approach!